kdb q Flip some columns in table to rows
I have a table like this:



ID
OriginalDate
PreviousDate
NextDate




1A
2024.01.01
2023.04.04
2024.03.01


1B
2024.01.02
2023.02.20
2024.05.01


1C
2024.01.03
2023.12.31
2024.02.01



tab: ([] ID: `1A`1B`1C; OriginalDate: 2024.01.01 2024.01.02 2024.01.03; PreviousDate: 2023.04.04 2023.02.20 2023.12.31; NextDate: 2024.03.01 2024.05.01 2024.02.01)

What I want to do is create a new table where each of the PreviousDate and NextDate values are their own rows while retaining the ID and OriginalDate values:



Date
ID
OriginalDate




2023.04.04
1A
2024.01.01


2024.03.01
1A
2024.01.01


2023.02.20
1B
2024.01.02


2024.05.01
1B
2024.01.02


2023.12.31
1C
2024.01.03


2024.02.01
1C
2024.01.03



I think I can use flip and individually pull the values, but I think there may be a faster way to get the goal table without going line by line. Appreciate any help on this as I'm looking for faster performance, not sure if using flip would be ideal for this scenario.

With flip and ungroup:
q)ungroup select Date:flip (PreviousDate;NextDate), ID, OriginalDate from tab
Date       ID OriginalDate
--------------------------
2023.04.04 1A 2024.01.01
2024.03.01 1A 2024.01.01
2023.02.20 1B 2024.01.02
2024.05.01 1B 2024.01.02
2023.12.31 1C 2024.01.03
2024.02.01 1C 2024.01.03

Query twice and join:
q)`ID xasc raze {?[x;();0b;`Date`ID`OriginalDate!y,`ID`OriginalDate]}[tab] each `PreviousDate`NextDate
Date       ID OriginalDate
--------------------------
2023.04.04 1A 2024.01.01
2024.03.01 1A 2024.01.01
2023.02.20 1B 2024.01.02
2024.05.01 1B 2024.01.02
2023.12.31 1C 2024.01.03
2024.02.01 1C 2024.01.03

Make table larger and test timing:
q)tab:1000000#tab
q)\ts ungroup select Date:flip (PreviousDate;NextDate), ID, OriginalDate from tab
670 291887296
q)\ts raze {?[x;();0b;`Date`ID`OriginalDate!y,`ID`OriginalDate]}[tab] each `PreviousDate`NextDate
3 33556112

Test results are the same: (notice sorting needed)
q)a:ungroup select Date:flip (PreviousDate;NextDate), ID, OriginalDate from tab
q)b:raze {?[x;();0b;`Date`ID`OriginalDate!y,`ID`OriginalDate]}[tab] each `PreviousDate`NextDate
q)(`Date`ID xasc a)~(`Date`ID xasc b)
1b


Interesting, thanks for showing me the execution times for both methods

here's another option
(,/){`ID`OriginalDate`Date xcol ![x;();0b;enlist y]}[tab]each`PreviousDate`NextDate

you delete each col and rename the remaining columns
